# Use referrer to generate url?

Tags: email, security, authentication

I'm trying to come up with a secure email verification / authentication redirect solution. Here's the basic scenario:

- A user registers with the site
- We send an email to the user to confirm the registration
- The email contains a url with a token to complete the process

This works, but I have a config value for the hostname that the service uses to generate the url. I want something a lot more flexible. My first thought was to use the referrer header, but I imagine that's pretty insecure. I also want to allow a subdomain per business, so I want the url generation to be pretty smart. At this point, I'm back to some config value of "allowed hosts".

I know this problem has been solved, but I'm having trouble putting together the right terms for google to surface a solution.

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly - would this be some kind of a generic email validator service that other applications would use?

Comment: No, it's just my application.

Answer (score 2):

The referrer header is only set within browsers. It will not be set to anything useful when a user clicks on a link in an email.

I don't think there's anything particular too google for. You got the right process: Generate a secret token, mail out a link containing it, done.

How you build the URLs is absolutely your business, and there's no "stock" or "standard" way to do it.

Comment: I was thinking of using the referrer to generate the url embedded in the email. My concern is someone could authenticate and then use the auth token to send an email to a user but forge the referrer. The recipient then gets an email that looks like it came from my site, but it takes the user to another site.

Comment: I don't understand: What referrer, then? The referrer header is set by the browser (sometimes) whenever you request a URL via HTTP, and contains the URL you're "coming from". So, this doesn't seem anything related to your problem?

Comment: The browser is sending the referrer just fine, and my url generation is using that referring to generate the url without issue, and the url in the email works correctly as well. My concern is whether or not I should even trust the  content of the referrer header.

Comment: If that is the general question: no, obviously not, since it's in total control of the user

Comment: Right, so I'm trying to come up with the "standard" solution for this problem. Do I create a list of allowable domains and then check the referrer to see if it's in the list?

Comment: I don't understand at all why you need the referrer at all!

Comment: I want to build a url that is subdomain and domain specific. If my app is running in production, I want the url to be www.mysite.com. If the app is running in test, I want the url to be test.mysite.com. Or maybe if I create a subdomain per tenant, I want the url to be tenant.mysite.com.

Comment: yeah, that's nice, but what does it have to do with a header sent by a browser when doing a request? (maybe start with: which request's header's referrer field do you plan to use at all?) Anyway, don't trust any headers sent by the user's machine – full stop.

Comment: I agree it's not safe, but i feel it is simple. I'm not sure of another way to know the domain/subdomain. My site is a single page app that is backed by an api gateway and a bunch of services. Any service might need to generate a url like this. I guess I could set a config value, but I was looking of a solution that didn't rely on a config.

Comment: so, include the domain in the database when you create the token that you mail out. It's not like your user wants to sign up on "any of your websites"; your application knows on behalf of which domain to work, so use that knowledge. But don't ask the user's browser

Comment: Yes, this covers the multi-tenant/subdomain. What would you suggest for the domain itself? My best guess is a config value.

Comment: I don't know how your application works internally. But it *has* to have a notion of the domain it's serving at any given moment. And you store your email tokens somewhere. So add the info which domain these tokens belong to alongside with the token. Problem solved.

Comment: Ok, this is the crux of it - in an architecture of many services, how could the services know the domain of the web app? They might not be on the same host. My services might be accessed under api.mysite.com, but the webapp serves from www.mysite.com. Even then, the apis are behind an api gateway and probably don't have dns entries. (In reality all my services are running in docker.)

Comment: but the service is *used* by the web app, so make that info flow.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to, but even the backend of the web app is behind nginx. I should be able to get the hostname header somehow, right?

Comment: I think I got it. I'm not sure why I latched on to the referrer, perhaps too many late hours. Simply using the hostname header or the x-forwarded-host header should be sufficient.